# How to install latest stable Drupal version from drupal/recommended-project branch?

Tags: composer

I've forked [drupal/recommended-project](https://github.com/drupal/recommended-project) and run `composer install` from the default branch (`8.8.x`), it installed the latest dev version (8.8.6-dev). There's also a tag 8.8.5 (latest stable as of now) which has the same `composer.json` with the exception of these lines:

```php
    "require-dev": {
        "drupal/core-dev": "^8.8"
    },
```

I've deleted these lines in branch `8.8.x` hoping this would install the latest stable version but it installed the dev version anyway. I don't want to use tags because I forked the upstream and have my own changes.

How can I install the latest stable version of Drupal from the default branch (`8.8.x`)?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of forking and running `composer install`, you should run `composer create-project drupal/recommended-project <project_root_dir>`. This will install the latest stable version of Drupal and you can of course add this to your version control system (don't forget to exclude all files that you don't have to track in your VCS).

When you use the `composer.lock` file from the GitHub repository directly, Composer installs the software versions as defined in the lock file (in this case the development versions).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know that `composer create-project` would work but in my case, I need a fork.

Comment: @csandanov – Simply create the project and then do your changes afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

I use a different one, [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project) and it installs the latest stable version.

> **Note:** That as of Drupal 8.8.0 [drupal-composer/drupal-project](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project)
>   has been **[deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#drupal-composer-drupal-project)** as an "official" source.
>
> **Note 2:** But the project it self is not deprecated **[drupal-composer/drupal-project has [not] been
>   deprecated](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/pull/550)**

If you look at its [composer.json](https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/blob/8.x/composer.json)

Under require it has

```
"require": {
    "drupal/core": "^8.8.0",
},
"require-dev": {
    "drupal/core-dev": "^8.8.0"
},
```

while yours doesn't; thus, this is why yours fetches the dev version.

Comment: I don't think that only changing the requirement for "drupal/core" from "^8.8" into "^8.8.0" is going to make any difference, if you keep the original lock file (of drupal/recommended-project). In that lock file the version for "drupal/core" is set to "8.8.x-dev" (with commit "3db6f1077351e63a8ba1d0fb858f0d942f41b938").

Comment: As a side note, as of Drupal 8.8.0 the drupal-composer/drupal-project has "officially" [been deprecated](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#drupal-composer-drupal-project). Though, it provides a lot of tools you probably want to include in your project.

Comment: @Watergate correct, he'll need to use `composer update` rather than `composer install` so it doesn't follow the lock file.

Comment: @Watergate deprecated... what a shame, ugh `drupal/recommended-project` looks so barebones.

Comment: I used `drupal-composer/drupal-project` before but now prefer to follow the official project. By the way it is NOT deprecated https://github.com/drupal-composer/drupal-project/pull/550

Comment: I'm still doing new sites from `drupal-composer/drupal-project`; I have used `drupal/recommended-project`, but in the end it looks just like a fresh `drupal-composer/drupal-project` once I got a good baseline set up for a real site.